# Android GLES 2.0: framebuffer rendering to half-float texture works on some devices, not others

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, framebuffer, render-to-texture

Using GLES 2.0 on Android, I am trying to render to a framebuffer backed by a texture. The texture and framebuffer are created like this:

```
final int GL_RGB16F_EXT = 0x881B;
GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGB, width, height, 0,
        GL_RGB16F_EXT, type, null);
GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
    GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle, 0);
```

For `type=GL_HALF_FLOAT_OES`, this works on some devices, but gives a `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT` status on others.

The texture was created with `GL_NEAREST` minify and magnify mode.

Note that on some devices (Nexus 5), the above works only when I use "`GL_RGB`" instead of "`GL_RGB16F_EXT`" as the internal format, on some (Nexus 6/7) it works only with `GL_RGB16F_EXT`, on some it works with both (Nexus 9) and on some it doesn't work with either (Nexus 4).

The weird thing is that all my devices, including the failing ones, report `GL_OES_texture_half_float` and `GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float`.

What else could I be missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct combination of arguments for ES 2.0 is:

```
final int GL_HALF_FLOAT_OES = 0x8D61;
GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGB, width, height, 0,
        GLES20.GL_RGB, GL_HALF_FLOAT_OES, null);
```

ES 2.0 unfortunately does not support sized internal formats for `glTexImage2D()`. It derives the internal format from the format/type parameters. Sized internal formats were added in ES 3.0.

Based on the [EGL_color_buffer_half_float spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/EXT_color_buffer_half_float.txt), `GL_RGB16F_EXT` is only supported as the internalformat for `glRenderbufferStorage()`.

Comment: Well, that was my first try also, but it does not appear to work on Nexus 6 or 7 (framebuffer status returns GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT). I agree that the EXT_color_buffer_half_float document mentions GL_RGB16F_EXT only for glRenderbufferStorage(), but that seems to be at odds with the actual behaviour of the GLES driver on some devices. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: The sad reality is that many mobile OpenGL drivers have lots of issues. So just because it doesn't work, this doesn't mean that the call is incorrect.